# Calculate the maximum distance between three points

Tags: java

I've created 3 arrays and I'm populating each array with 10 random numbers (points). Now I need to take the points from each array and calculate the greatest distance between 2 of the 3 points. I.E. the distance between x and z is greater than x and y/z and y/etc. How would I do such calculations?

```
public static double max(double[] x, double[] y, double[] z) {
    // Calculate the maximum distance
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double xCoordArray = new double[10];
    double yCoordArray = new double[10];
    double zCoordArray = new double[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        xCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        yCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        zCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }

    Point3D object0 = new Point32(xCoordArray[0], yCoordArray[0], zCoordArray[0]);

    double maxDistance = max(xCoordArray, yCoordArray, zCoordArray);

    System.out.println(object0);
    System.out.println(maxDistance);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate distance between points? Do you know how to sort?

Comment: three points `(x,y,z)`.. isn't it one (3D) point? do you want to calculate the distance between points or the axis values? please rephrase your question more clearly..

Comment: @Sotirios, No, I don't know how to calculate the distance between points and yes, I do know how to sort.

Comment: @Yohanes, I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: Then I suggest you research how to calculate distances between points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: New answer here at the top. Old answer is below.

```
public class SimplepointsDistance {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] xCoordArray = new double[10];
    double[] yCoordArray = new double[10];
    double[] zCoordArray = new double[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        xCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        yCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        zCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }


    int[] xyDistance = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        xyDistance[i] = (int) Math.abs(xCoordArray[i] - yCoordArray[i]);
    }

    int[] xzDistance = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        xzDistance[i] = (int) Math.abs(xCoordArray[i] - zCoordArray[i]);
    }

    int[] yzDistance = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        yzDistance[i] = (int) Math.abs(yCoordArray[i] - zCoordArray[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        int maxDistance = xyDistance[i];
        int maxDistancePair = 1; //understand 1 means xy, 2 means xz, 3 means yz;

        if (xzDistance[i] > maxDistance) {
            maxDistance = xzDistance[i];
            maxDistancePair = 2;
        }

        if (yzDistance[i] > maxDistance) {
            maxDistance = yzDistance[i];
            maxDistancePair = 3;
        }

        switch (maxDistancePair) {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Greatest distance in set " + i + " is " + maxDistance + " between x and y");
            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("Greatest distance in set " + i + " is " + maxDistance + " between x and z");
            break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.println("Greatest distance in set " + i + " is " + maxDistance + " between y and z");
            break;

        }



    }

}
```

}

So all we do is record the distances between pairs (in my xyDistance-like arrays), then loop through them and pick out the biggest distance from all 3 pairs and display it.

**EDIT:** So the question was edited while I was working on the answer, the code below does **not** solve the problem but I'll keep it there in case it comes in handy to anyone else. I'm working on the new answer now.

You can find the distance between two points in 3-dimensional space by using the Pythagorean theorem:

Given two points, A and B, with attributes x, y, and z, the distance between them is:

```
squareroot( (A.x - B.x)^2 + (A.y - B.y)^2 + (A.z - B.z)^2 )
```

Your question is a bit unclear, you ask about 3 points but you seem to be generating 10 points. I'll assume you want the biggest distance between any 2 of the 10 points.

You need to cycle through each set of points and record the points and distances.

```
public class PointsDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] xCoordArray = new double[10];
        double[] yCoordArray = new double[10];
        double[] zCoordArray = new double[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            xCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            yCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            zCoordArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        }


        double distance[] = new double[45];
        int setCounter = 0;
        double maxDistance = 0;
        int maxI = -1;
        int maxJ = -1;

        for (int i=0 ;i<9;i++){
            for ( int j=i+1;j<10;j++){
                distance[setCounter] = Math.sqrt ( Math.pow (xCoordArray[i] - xCoordArray[j], 2) + Math.pow (yCoordArray[i] - yCoordArray[j], 2) + Math.pow (zCoordArray[i] - zCoordArray[j], 2));

                System.out.println("Testing " + i + " and " + j + " with distance " + distance[setCounter]);
                if (distance[setCounter] > maxDistance) {
                    maxDistance = distance[setCounter ++];
                    maxI = i;
                    maxJ = j;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Maximum distance is " + maxDistance);
        System.out.println("Between point " + maxI + ": " + xCoordArray[maxI] + ", " + yCoordArray[maxI] + ", " +  zCoordArray[maxI]);
        System.out.println("And "  + maxJ + ": " + xCoordArray[maxJ] + ", " + yCoordArray[maxJ] + ", " +  zCoordArray[maxJ]);
    }
}
```

So a bit of explanation is in order here:

```
double distance[] = new double[45];
```

45 is the sum of 9 + 8 + 7... + 1, which is the number of pairs I need to match: I don't need to match any point with itself, so the first point needs to match the following 9. The second point doesn't need to be checked against the first one, because that's already been done, so we check it against the following 8.  The conditions in my for loops ( `int i=0 ;i<9;i++` and `int j=i+1;j<10;j++`) are set up to minimize the amount of work we have to do.

After that it's just recording the biggest matches and displaying them at the end.

Comment: Thank you, Devon. I know my question was not clear, I was having trouble trying to explain myself. I appreciate the explanation you've provided and now I have some research to do.